# vue.js route problem on my server - does not work

Tags: vue.js

I have routes, like this:

```
/about
/experience
```

When i click  localhost/about ,  localhost/experience   its working.

But when i upload the files to the my server like test.com, if i try to go test.com/experience its not working. its giving an 404 error.
[image]

But if i go to the pages **from the homepage, its working.** What is the problem?

Answer (score 3):

I solwed with htaccess

```js
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
    </IfModule>
```

Answer (score 2):

Your server is not configured to rewrite missing files (HTTP 404 errors) to your `/index.html`
If you're using nginX, this can be achieved like this:

```
....
    location / {
      try_files $uri @rewrite;
    }

    location @rewrite {
      rewrite ^(.*)$ /index.html last;        
    }
```

If you can not control your web server configuration - you will need to switch from `history` to `hash` mode in the Vue-Router settings.